# Wix Burn Bootstrapper Uninstalling Crystal Report on Major Upgrade

Tags: crystal-reports, wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper, burn

I am using wix burn for my bootstrapper and every time I have upgrade to my application Crystal Reports runtime gets uninstalled. Can someone please help me fix this?

Bundle.wxs

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" 
     xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">

  <?include Variables.wxi ?>

  <Bundle Name="!(loc.BundleName)"
          Version="$(var.Version)"
                Manufacturer="!(loc.Manufacturer)"
                HelpTelephone="!(loc.HelpPhone)"
                Copyright="!(loc.Copyright)"
          UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)"
          IconSourceFile="$(var.MainApplicationImagesFolder)\Car_Count_Report_Flat.ico" >
    <!--SplashScreenSourceFile="$(var.MainApplicationImagesFolder)\BurnSplashScreen.bmp" >-->

    <bal:Condition Message="This install requires Windows 7 Service Pack 1 or Higher">
      ((VersionNT >= v6.1) AND (ServicePackLevel >= 1) OR (VersionNT >= v6.3))
    </bal:Condition>

    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" />
    <WixVariable Id="WixStdbaLicenseRtf" Value="$(var.EULAFolder)\EULA_en-US.rtf" />
    <WixVariable Id="WixStdbaLogo" Value="$(var.MainApplicationImagesFolder)\car_counter_report_icon_64.png" />

    <!-- Checks the Crystal Reports Registry Values -->
    <!--<util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Crystal Reports"
                      Value="CRRuntime64Version" Format="raw" Variable="CRRuntime64Version" Result="value" Win64="yes"/>-->

    <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Crystal Reports"
                         Value="CRRuntime32Version" Format="raw" Variable="CRRuntime32Version" Result="value"/>

    <!-- Checks the Main Application Registry Values -->
    <!--<util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Key="Software\Saunders Creative Strategies\Kaady\Car Count Report"
                        Value="Version" Format="raw" Variable="x64Version" Result="value" Win64="yes"/>-->

    <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Key="Software\Saunders Creative Strategies\Kaady\Car Count Report"
                         Value="Version" Format="raw" Variable="x86Version" Result="value"/>

    <!-- Adds Local Variables -->
    <Variable Name="CRRUNTIMEUPGRADE" bal:Overridable="yes" Type="numeric" Value="1" />

    <Chain>
      <!-- TODO: Define the list of chained packages. -->
      <!-- <MsiPackage SourceFile="path\to\your.msi" /> -->
      <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx45Redist"/>
      <PackageGroupRef Id ="CrystalReportsRuntime"/>
      <PackageGroupRef Id="MainApplicationFile"/>
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

InstallationFiles.wxs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">

  <?include Variables.wxi ?>
  <Fragment>
    <!-- Crystal Reports Runtime -->
    <PackageGroup Id="CrystalReportsRuntime">

      <!--<?if $(var.Platform) = x64 ?>--><!--
      --><!--<MsiPackage Id ="CRRuntime64"
                   DownloadUrl="$(var.CRHttp)/$(var.CRx64Msi)"
                   SourceFile="$(var.3rdPartyApplicationFiles)\$(var.CRx64Msi)"
                   Name="$(var.CRx64Msi)"
                   Vital ="yes"
                   Compressed="no"
                   ForcePerMachine="yes"
                   InstallCondition="NOT CRRuntime64Version OR (CRRuntime64Version &lt; &quot;$(var.CRVersion)&quot;)" >
        <MsiProperty Name="UPGRADE" Value="[CRRUNTIMEUPGRADE]" />
      </MsiPackage>--><!--
      --><!--<?else ?>-->
      <MsiPackage Id ="CRRuntime32"
                DownloadUrl="$(var.CRHttp)/$(var.CRx86Msi)"
                SourceFile="$(var.3rdPartyApplicationFiles)\$(var.CRx86Msi)"
                Name="$(var.CRx86Msi)"
                Vital ="yes"
                Compressed="no"
                ForcePerMachine="yes"
                Visible="yes" 
                Permanent="yes"
                InstallCondition="NOT CRRuntime32Version AND (NOT (CRRuntime32Version = &quot;$(var.CRVersion)&quot;))" >
        <MsiProperty Name="UPGRADE" Value="[CRRUNTIMEUPGRADE]" />
      </MsiPackage>
      <!--<?endif ?>-->
    </PackageGroup>

    <PackageGroup Id="MainApplicationFile">
      <!--<MsiPackage Id="MainApplicationx64Msi" Vital="yes" Compressed="yes" ForcePerMachine="yes" Cache="yes"
                 Name="$(var.Mainx64Msi)"
                 InstallCondition="NOT x64Version OR (x64Version &lt; &quot;$(var.Version)&quot;)"
                 SourceFile="$(var.MainApplicationx64MsiFile)\$(var.Mainx64Msi)"/>-->

      <MsiPackage Id="MainApplicationx86Msi" Vital="yes" Compressed="yes" ForcePerMachine="yes" Cache="yes"
                  Name="$(var.Mainx86Msi)" 
                  Visible="no"
                  InstallCondition="NOT x86Version OR (x86Version &lt; &quot;$(var.Version)&quot;)"
                  SourceFile="$(var.MainApplicationx86MsiFile)\$(var.Mainx86Msi)"/>
    </PackageGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Thank you
Shane

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the install log in the user's temp directory, you would see that the upgrade bundle doesn't think it should install the CRRuntime32 because the InstallCondition is false.  Burn uses the MSI's upgrade table to do the same logic that you're trying to do.  If the Crystal Reports MSI is authored correctly, you should be able to just drop your install condition and let Burn decide whether it needs to be installed.

Comment: I have crystal reports installed already and it is saying false if already installed. I was looking in wix .net dll and i changed it this `CRRuntime32Version &lt; &quot;$(var.CRVersion)&quot;` but I remove the logic i have in my installer and let the burn do it.

Comment: I remove the install conditions and it worked just fine. I installed old version of Crystal Reports and let upgrade that when i install the newer version of the application. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You should use DetectCondition instead of InstallCondition. The first answers: Is it installed?; The second: For a bundle installation, is it wanted?

The way you have it, burn removes CR when it is present during installation because the logic says it's not wanted.

Comment: This a MSI not an EXE, so i had to use InstallCondition and not DetectCondition. Yes it was installed, and yes, it is wanted when you first install the application and if there update either i wanted to update, but I used @Sean Hall reply to fix the issue.